# Spacing problem in TOC

Tags: table-of-contents

I am working on my thesis and using a template provided by the university. I have a problem in list of figures. Here is the university guideline for the table of contents: "*In the Table of Contents, titles cannot go all the way to the page number. There must be at least some leading periods between each title and page number. Inversely, there cannot be a line of only leading periods and a page number. There must be at least one word on the line which contains the leading periods and page number.*" However, I do not have control over the spacing between the end of titles and the page numbers. The figure below demonstrates the problem. I would really appreciate it if somebody could help me. I used \stackunder{}{} to make the double spacing between consecutive titles.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: (a) The university should have provided such a *good* TeX template. Ask someone graduated for one is a better idea. (b) You may customize your titles by `\section[title version a]{title version b}`. (c) learn `tocloft` to see if there are any other options. (d) it is ridiculous to have mandatory leading lines if there is no need to lead.

Answer (score 2):

Add this to your preamble

```
\usepackage{tocloft} % package to manipulate ToC, LoF and LoT

% reducing dot separation to make it look like a dotted line
\renewcommand{\cftdotsep}{1}

% increasing width for page number for ToC, LoF and LoT
\cftsetpnumwidth{1cm}

% increasing right margin which makes width available for titles smaller
% hence grater the value smaller the title width
% for your document try to adjust the following value of 3cm by increa-
% sing or decreasing whichever suits you
\cftsetrmarg{3cm}
```

Comment: It's usually a good rule of thumb to add the option `titles` to `tocloft`: `\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}`, otherwise the package will hijack the typesetting of titles for the table of contents and the various lists.